# Subquery in from clause, Invalid Identifier in Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from iiasa_inventory.inv_device    d                         
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_type ty on d.type_id = ty.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_category c on ty.category_id = c.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_device_2_barcode b on b.device_id = d.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_barcodes bc on b.barcode_id = bc.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_status s on d.status = s.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_brand br on ty.brand_id = br.id
  left join iiasa_inventory.inv_supplier su on su.id = d.supplier_id
  left join iiasa_inventory.inv_supplier sup on sup.id = d.maintenance_with
  left join (select distinct device_id from 
  iiasa_inventory.inv_device_2_persons_cc) dp
  on dp.device_id = d.id 
  where dp.active = 1
```

I am trying to select my data but the where-clause says that "dp.active" is an INVALID Identifier. This is probably because the table dp is in the subquery. I have tried to give it an alias name and some other things I found while browsing stackoverflow, but I cant seem to find a solution. Any idea?

This is Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: You are not querying for `active` in your subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the check for `active = 1` in the subquery as shown below.

```
select * from iiasa_inventory.inv_device    d                         
                                  join iiasa_inventory.inv_type ty on d.type_id = ty.id
                                  join iiasa_inventory.inv_category c on ty.category_id = c.id
                                  join iiasa_inventory.inv_device_2_barcode b on b.device_id = d.id
                                  join iiasa_inventory.inv_barcodes bc on b.barcode_id = bc.id
                                  join iiasa_inventory.inv_status s on d.status = s.id
                                  join iiasa_inventory.inv_brand br on ty.brand_id = br.id
                                  left join iiasa_inventory.inv_supplier su on su.id = d.supplier_id
                                  left join iiasa_inventory.inv_supplier sup on sup.id = d.maintenance_with
                                  left join (select distinct device_id from iiasa_inventory.inv_device_2_persons_cc where active = 1) dp on dp.device_id = d.id
```

Comment: oh my god, How could I miss this. Thanks a lot, it has been a long day ^^

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not selecting `active` column in dp.

```
select * from iiasa_inventory.inv_device    d                         
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_type ty on d.type_id = ty.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_category c on ty.category_id = c.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_device_2_barcode b on b.device_id = d.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_barcodes bc on b.barcode_id = bc.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_status s on d.status = s.id
  join iiasa_inventory.inv_brand br on ty.brand_id = br.id
  left join iiasa_inventory.inv_supplier su on su.id = d.supplier_id
  left join iiasa_inventory.inv_supplier sup on sup.id = d.maintenance_with
  left join (select distinct device_id,active from iiasa_inventory.inv_device_2_persons_cc) dp on dp.device_id = d.id 
where dp.active = 1
```

**OR** you can just filter from the subquery itself. Like:

```
left join (select distinct device_id 
        from iiasa_inventory.inv_device_2_persons_cc 
        where active=1) dp on dp.device_id = d.id
```